# How to find out if user has specified a value for a default argument?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, optional-parameters, default-arguments

I have a C++ function with a default argument.

In the function, if I find that this argument has the default value, there can be two possibilities - (A) user calling this function did not supply a value for this argument, hence default value was assigned (B) user supplied the default value for this argument.

I need to be able to differentiate between these two cases. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Use two different overloaded functions.

Comment: What would that solve ? What are you trying to solve exactly ?

Comment: The correct choice of default value depends on the context and if the user has not specified a value, I need to make an intelligent choice of the default depending on the context. However, if the value comes from the user, I intend to use that without worrying about the context.

Comment: So, if the user doesn't provide a value, the default value is useless. Then why do you have a default value in the first place ? Use overloads as n.m. and Peter K suggest.

Comment: Yes, use different functions, since they *do different things*: One function makes an intelligent choice itself, the other uses what the user supplies. The first can call the second, of course.

Comment: "a default argument" = one default argument. If you have something with 10 default arguments, you should question your design. If you have something with 10 default arguments and you need to distinguish between explicitly passing or implicitly passing the default argument in all of them, you are occupying someone else's position, quit and take up knitting.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the compiler substitutes the default argument at the call site. There is no way to distinguish this from a user providing the exact same argument.

You could use two different functions to distinguish the two cases: one that has the argument for which you wanted to specify the default, and one without.

Answer (score 0):

Use overloaded functions.

```
void do_great()
{
    // default operation
}

void do_great(int value)
{
    // non-default operation
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class A
{
private:
   const int _defaultValue = 0;

public:
   void function(int userValue = _defaultValue)
   {
      if (userValue != _defaultValue)
         ....;
      else
         ....;
....
```

the same for functions:

```
namespace { const int defaultValue = 0; }
void function(int userValue = defaultValue);
```

Comment: If the user provides 0 as argument, he still will not be able to distinguish between defaulted or user provided argument.

Comment: well, in such case only overloading: `void function()` and `void function(int userValue);`